# How to allow non-root users to mount bitlocker encrypted external drives?

Tags: mount, automounting, external-hdd, disk-encryption, udisks

As a non-root user I would like to be able to mount external hard drives which have been encrypted with microsoft bitlocker. The admin (with root access) can set something up if I can tell him how to do it, and it doesn't compromise security.

I can mount encrypted drives *with* root using [dislocker](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-mount-bitlocker-encrypted.html), and I can mount unencrypted drives **without** root using `udisk`. I just can't figure out how to combine them (or if there are other tools I should look at).

**Mounting bitlocker drives with root:**

```
sudo dislocker /dev/sda1 -u<password> -- /media/bitlocker
sudo mount -o loop /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file /media/bitlockermount
```

**Mounting unencrypted drives without root:**

```
udiskctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Simplest way would be to have the admin provide two scripts for mounting and unmounting, and edit `sudoers` to allow some or all normal users to execute those scripts as root.

Answer (score 0):

Create the directories `bitlocker` and `bitlockermount` under `/media`. Then you can add the following to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/disk-by-id/... /media/bitlocker fuse.dislocker user-password=<password>,nofail 0 0
/media/bitlocker/dislockerfile /media/bitlockermount auto user,nofail 0 0
```

The first line may need the `user` attribute, also. Test it out.

Comment: Wouldn't this make your Bitlocker password visible to everyone with access to `/etc/fstab` (viz. every single user by default)?

Comment: Another problem is that this would have to be done by the admin every time a different drive was to be plugged in. It might be worthwhile even with both issues though, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: Wtf, who downvotes a correct answer?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but the answer doesn't fully address the original question, and is just a copy/paste of background research given in the question itself, without adding anything useful.

Comment: Well, what do you think how most questions get answered. If you answer questions out of your scope, it is nothing more than "let me google that for you". That is ok, since many can't even do that themselves. Anyway, im good at looking things up. There is no other better answer, unless the author of the package or it's team is gonna respond. No justification for a downvote. Noone forces to upvote.